# "get a coating"

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

I recently saw the expression "get a (real) coating" in [this book review](http://www.theguardian.com/football/blog/2011/jul/20/im-not-really-here-paul-lake-review):

> Swales, perhaps unsurprisingly, is the only guy who gets a real coating, but only in passing

But I just cannot figure out what it means as I can't find it anywhere.

Any clue?

Comment: It's not at all common, but [to coat someone off](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_does_the_saying_coating_someone_off_mean) is (dated, imho) SE UK slang for *say bad things about someone*. So in your context, Swales is the only guy who comes in for heavy criticism.

Comment: This is a great example of idiomatic writing biting the author in the ass. I had zero understanding of this sentence until I read answers below. This must be almost exclusively British English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought this use of *coating* was rather common, but looking in a selection of online dictionaries, I have only been able to find it documented in [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/coating), who define it (sense 3) as:

> *(English Midlands, dialect)* a severe rebuke; ticking-off

So the sense is here that the author of the book writes some angry, nasty, negative, or at least critical things about this Swales person (whoever that is—someone who’s known not to be in good standing with the author, at any rate).

The word can also be used when referring to physical ‘rebukes’, to mean a sound thrashing:

> He was attacked by some thugs on the way home from the pub the other night. Got a real coating too, by the sounds of it.

I have always thought that this sense comes from the use of *coating* to mean a layer of paint on a wall: the person who gets the real coating is figuratively covered in a thin layer of punches or criticisms. Thinking more closely about it, I realise it might just as well be an extension of the normal meaning of a *coat*, i.e., the person is ‘dressed’ in punches and criticism, wearing them like a coat.

Comment: I suspect the allusion might be to *give him a coating **of tar and feathers*** (as a way of publicly calling attention to his shortcomings), but I've hardly ever heard any variations of ***coat*** used in this way. Much more common is *give him a **pasting***, which (as with *coating*) often means subject to a physical rather than verbal attack.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Interesting. To me, _pasting_ is almost unknown, while _coating_ is perfectly normal and colloquial. I don’t recall ever hearing anyone say _pasting_ in conversation—it’s one of those words for me that you read in books and understand, but never really hear anyone use in real life. Anyway, I like your idea of the tar and feathers origin—never occurred to me before, but it sounds very plausible.

Comment: Checking Google Books for [*gave him a coating*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22gave+him+a+coating%22+-%22coating+of%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (excluding *"coating **of**"*, which usually continues with *tar* or similar), there's only one relevant result. But there are plenty of [*gave him a pasting*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22gave+him+a+pasting%22+-%22pasting+of%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), which I still hear all the time.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can’t seem to find it used much online, either. Odd. I would be more likely to say that someone _gets_ a real coating (and always with an adjective: real, proper, right, thorough, etc.) than that someone _gives_ someone else one. Not sure why. Trouncings, thrashings, lashings, poundings, and I presume pastings as well all work just fine in either direction, giving or getting; but coatings seem to be gotten more than given, at least in my head.

Comment: Sticking to Google Books, I find a few dozen instances of *got a real/right pasting*, but none at all for either adjective with *coating*. I'm not saying it's *never* used, but I do think *coating* is both relatively uncommon and somewhat dated compared to *pasting* (and *thrashing* - but that's *always* used of physical assault, so far as I know).

Comment: Yeah, I've never heard "coating" in this sense, but "pasting" has long been known to me in the sense of getting beat up -- usually not enough to threaten life or cause long-term disability, but sufficiently to make someone want to crawl off and lick their wounds for awhile.

Answer (score 1):

Superficially, *a real coating* and *a real hiding* may both seem related to outer coverings.  However, noun *[hiding](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hiding#Noun_2)* (“A beating or spanking”) apparently derives from verb *[hide](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hide#Verb_2)* (“To beat with a whip made from hide”), as distinct from the [noun's](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hide#Noun) sense, “One's own life or personal safety, especially when in peril”, where *hide* is like *skin*.

Note, [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+real+coating%2Ca+real+pasting%2Ca+real+hiding&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20real%20pasting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20real%20hiding%3B%2Cc0) shows *a real coating* to have little or no currency in books, and shows *a real pasting* as slightly less common than *a real hiding*.

The difference is more pronounced in [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got%20a%20coating,got%20a%20pasting,got%20a%20hiding&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgot%20a%20coating%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20a%20pasting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20a%20hiding%3B%2Cc0) for *got a coating, got a pasting, got a hiding*, with the latter far more common than the first two.

Comment: Yeah, "hiding" has always implied to me beating with a whip or, more likely, a belt.  You're apt to get a hiding from your dad and a pasting from the neighborhood bully.

Comment: @HotLicks I've always thought that if you got a hiding it meant that _your_ hide got beaten, whatever it was beaten with,

Comment: @BoldBen - I never worried much about the details -- I just knew I wanted to avoid it!

Answer (score 1):

In London in early 1980s I heard the phrase used to mean making fun of someone too - not physical violence but lighthearted verbal banter.
 e.g. 'He had a ridiculous haircut and we gave him a right coating about it.' or 'You'll get a coating if you turn up looking like mate.'

Answer (score 1):

My granny told me that her husband, a policeman, in the early part of last century, wore a weatherproof cape. To prevent it blowing over his head, he filled the hem with leadshot. An uncooperative client was liable for a good "coating" with that cape...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).